# How to combine these inputfilters for the EditText?

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

I'm new in android programming. I have created an material app with that users can track their weight. (P.S) I have edittext for inputing value. I already tried to make two inputfilters, but they aren't work properly:

Code of them:

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilterMinMax(1,140)});
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(1)});

public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter implements InputFilter {

private final int decimalDigits;

/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param decimalDigits maximum decimal digits
 */
public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(int decimalDigits) {
    this.decimalDigits = decimalDigits;
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source,
                           int start,
                           int end,
                           Spanned dest,
                           int dstart,
                           int dend) {


    int dotPos = -1;
    int len = dest.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = dest.charAt(i);
        if (c == '.' || c == ',') {
            dotPos = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (dotPos >= 0) {

        // protects against many dots
        if (source.equals(".") || source.equals(","))
        {
            return "";
        }
        // if the text is entered before the dot
        if (dend <= dotPos) {
            return null;
        }
        if (len - dotPos > decimalDigits) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    return null;
}

}
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

private int min, max;

public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    try {
        int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
        if (isInRange(min, max, input))
            return null;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }
    return "";
}

private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
    return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
}
}
```

With that code, user can enter as many digits before decimal point, as he want, but only one symbol after decimal point. E. g.: he can enter 145.6, 2452.5, 54356.5, 34523423.5.

I want to allow user to enter only numbers 1-140 before decimal point, but only one symbol after decimal point: 86.5, 45.7, 99.9, 112.4, 140.0.

Please, help me to change my code for that work

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
InputFilter NumberDecimalFilter = new InputFilter() {
                        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                            int dots = 0;
                            int numbersAfterDot = 0;
                            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i)) && source.charAt(i) != '.')  {
                return "";
            }else{
                if(source.charAt(i) == '.'){
                    if(dots > 0 || i == 0){
                      return "";
                    }else{
                       dots ++;
                    }
                }else{
                if(dots > 0 && numbersAfterDot > 0){
                      return "";
                    }else{
                       if(dots > 0){
                          numbersAfterDot ++;
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;  
                    };  

    editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { NumberDecimalFilter });
```

to check the range and the size of the decimal part i recomend you to use edittext.gettext().toString and Double.parseDouble() but you will not can input more than 1 decimal and you can only input number and only one dot as much

Comment: i have a numberdecimal edittext and i can input only numbers. Why i need isNumber?

Comment: Error:(130, 34) error: cannot find symbol variable length Error:(133, 38) error: cannot find symbol variable length
Error:(144, 25) error: cannot find symbol variable sources
Error:(144, 45) error: no suitable method found for parseInt(CharSequence)

Comment: method Integer.parseInt(String,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method Integer.parseInt(String) is not applicable
(actual argument CharSequence cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)
Error:(144, 79) error: no suitable method found for parseInt(CharSequence)
method Integer.parseInt(String,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: method Integer.parseInt(String) is not applicable
(actual argument CharSequence cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Comment: sorry i saw the charsequence as string

Comment: try to replace source for source.tostring

Comment: the is number is for che that the string is a number and not breaks using the method parseInt

Comment: if it works, i'll see how to do the same for the decimals, this is only for the number field of integers

Comment: input is a parameter that function recibes an String and return a boolean, but the other answer is better (i think)

Comment: the proble was that i miss the "()" the method is "length()" but it doesn't matter because i post a new solution. i hope it helps

Comment: with that code i cant type any number to the edittext.

Comment: try changing the return "" and return null (i changed in the code)

Comment: with that changes you can only type numbers in the first edit text and number with a dot in the second

Comment: i think you have an edittext for the integer and another for the decimal

Comment: ok. I changed the solution to write only numbers. it's helpfull?